# Definir Atributo a partir de radiobutton JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Estou montando um formulário genérico para cadastro de pessoa física e jurídica e a definição parte de dois `RadioButton's` que alteram os campos, após preenchidos eles são enviados para um `Servlet`e depois para uma classe `DAO`, o formulário possui diferentes campos tipo **CPF** para PF e **CNPJ** para PJ, tenho uma condição no `Servlet` que precisa validar o tipo selecionado para poder jogar os campos na classe `Usuario()`, e quero saber como posso fazer essa validação em **JSP** a partir do rádio button?

Estrutura básica:

```
 <form>
    <!-- Tipo de Cadastro -->                                    
    <input id="radiopf" type="radio" name="Type" checked value="pessoaPF">
    <label for="radiopf">Pessoa Fisica</label>            
    <input id="radiopj" type="radio" name="Type" value="pessoaPJ"> 
    <label for="radiopj">Pessoa Juridica</label>
 </form>

 <!-- Formulário de Cadastro -->
 <form id="frm" name="FormCadastro" action="Controle" method="POST"> 
   <fieldset id = "PF">
       <!-- Campos Pessoa Física -->
   </fieldset>

   <fieldset id = "PJ">
       <!-- Campos Pessoa Jurídica-->
   </fieldset>
   <input type="submit" value="Gravar" name="Cadastrar" onclick="return Validate();" />
 </form>
```

OBS: **`Validate();`** é uma validação em `JavaScript` feita antes de enviar os dados para o `Servlet` verifica tipo de dado, tamanho, formatação, campos nulos etc.
**`Controle`** é o `Servlet` que recebe os dados via `request.getParameter()`
para enviar para a classe `DAO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui...

```
//html dentro do mesmo <form id="frm"></form>
<input id="radiopf" type="radio" name="Type" checked value="pessoaPF">
<input id="radiopf" type="radio" name="Type" value="pessoaPJ">

//Servlet
if(request.getParameter("Type") != null){
    if(request.getParameter("Type").equals("pessoaPF")) {
         //Atribuição Pessoa Física dentro da classe Usuario();
    }
    if(request.getParameter("Type").equals("pessoaPJ")) {
         //Atribuição Pessoa Jurídica dentro da classe Usuario();
    }
 }
```